# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1,"

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I have made a static library using `OpenCV`. and now I want to integrate it in my project but it shows error `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`

Comment: You have build the static library for witch architecture ?

Comment: please check this link:-https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/255

Comment: @vivekDas I have build for universal architecture.

Comment: As per the error it says your static library does not build for arm64 architecture. So check it again.